# How can I disable/enable a login button in Keycloak?

Tags: javascript, keycloak, freemarker

I'm styling a Keycloak login page and I'm trying to implement logic with JavaScript so that the login button can only be activated if the person enters a username and password. I tested the logic in another file/project and it worked, but in Keycloak it is not working. Below is the code I am trying to use.

In the .ftl file (login button):

```
<input type="hidden" id="id-hidden-input" name="credentialId" <#if auth.selectedCredential?has_content>value="${auth.selectedCredential}"</#if>/>
   <input tabindex="4" class="form-button" name="login" id="kc-login" type="submit" value="${msg("Login")}" disabled />
```

My username input:

```
<input id="username" class="login-field" placeholder="${msg("Username")}" type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" onchange="toggleButton()">
```

My password input:

```
<input id="password" class="login-field custom" placeholder="${msg("Password")}" type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" onchange="toggleButton()">
```

And the logic with JavaScript:

```
function toggleButton() {
   const username = document.querySelector('#username').value;
   const password = document.querySelector('#password').value;

   if (username && password) {
       document.querySelector('#kc-login').disabled = false;
           return
   }
        document.querySelector('#kc-login').disabled = true;
}
```

Can anybody help me, please? I searched and didn't find a solution for this. Do I need to do anything beyond this? It's my first time with Keycloak, so I really have no idea what it could be

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add event handlers to call the `toggleButton()` function on the `username` and `password` inputs `onkeyup=toggleButton()`.

Comment: In fact, I'm using onchange="toggleButton()" in my inputs, I tried what you suggested but it didn't work either...

<input id="username" class="login-field" placeholder="${msg("Username")}" type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" onchange="toggleButton()">

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. I wouldn't use onchange as that will only trigger when the input loses focus. You might want to use F12 in the browser to see the console to see if there are any errors or if your code is even there. If you are using a custom Login theme, did you set it up in Realm settings?